# How to run a Windows Service Application from a WPF application method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, service, windows-10

I know that starting a process from a Windows Service application is impossible(or very difficult due to windows services running in an isolated process). However, is it possible to run a windows service from a method inside a WPF application? If so, how do I do it in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First, some background:**

A Windows Service (WS) is a background process that runs without a user interface (ignoring you naughty WS with **Allow service to interact with desktop** ticked) and can run before a user has logged in.  Because of this WS may run in the context of **LOCALSYSTEM**; **NETWORK SERVICE** or even an explicit user account dedicated for the service amongst others.  Services that start with Windows during boot and before a user has logged in are known as *Auto start* services.  There's even a beastie known as *delayed auto-start*.

> However, is it possible to run a windows service from a method inside a WPF application?

If by "run" you mean how to trigger a previously deployed WS to start, then "Yes!".

Consider the example below and imagine that the method `SomeMethodInMyWpfApp()` exists somewhere in your WPF app.  Then by simply calling this method, we obtain a reference to the service controller for a WS known as *"MissPiggyService"* by name.  Once we have a reference, we can query as to the state of the service.  Is it running?  It is in the process of starting?  If the answer to both these questions is "no" then we issue a start service request.  We do this because it's generally not nice to tell the SC to start a service that's already in the process of starting.

```
void SomeMethodInMyWpfApp()
{

    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MissPiggyService");
    if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running && 
        sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
    { 
        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

However, if by *"However, is it possible to run a windows service from a method inside a WPF application?"* can you create; replicate and run the functionality of an external WS within your WPF app - then no.

WS are not regular processes.  For one you can't embed one process within another (at least I don't think you can, we're not talking about AppDomains here) but more importantly, a WS needs to be able to respond to the Windows Service Controller when it asks your WS to start, stop, and possibly pause.  Something a regular process does not implement.